# Is it possible to prove that this function of the truncated binomial is decreasing?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, truncated-distributions

Suppose a random variable is binomially distributed with $G$ trials and success probability $p$.

Consider the expected proportion of successes, given that the proportion of successes is at least $k$:

$$
\bar{p}_k = \frac{1}{G}\frac{\sum_{l=kG}^Gl\phi(l,G,p)}{\sum_{l=kG}^G\phi(l,G,p)}
$$

where $\phi(l,G,p)$ is the binomial probability mass function.

This is increasing from $k$ to 1 as $p$ increases from 0 to 1. It also has slope less than 1 over that range.

From drawing graphs, it seems that the expression

$$
\frac{\bar{p}_k - p}{1 - p}
$$

is decreasing from $k$ to 0 as $p$ goes from 0 to 1.

Can anyone see how I could prove this?